# How to randomly sample all the columns present in a dataframe?

Tags: r

So I have a data frame with several columns and I want to create another data frame that is basically a small sample of the first. I want the size of it to be 10% of the original data frame's size.
I tried this:

```
sample(df,length(df$column1)*0.1)
```

but it returns an error:

> Error in sample.int(length(x), size, replace, prob) :
> cannot take a sample larger than the population when 'replace = FALSE'

Thank you in advance for any suggestion